# Type of _id in mongoose wrong when returning in express api

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js, angular-fullstack

I´ve set up a simple test(mocha and should) and I´m testing that the report I save is the same as the one I get. I'd prefer to use deep.equal but since the _id won't equal im getting stuck.

```js
var report = new Report();

        describe('GET:id /api/reports', function () {

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            report.save(function (err, result) {
                if (err) return (done(err));
                result._id.should.eql(report._id);
                done();
            });
        });

        afterEach(function (done) {
            Report.remove().exec().then(function () {
                done();
            });
        });

        before(function (done) {
            Report.remove().exec().then(function () {
                done();
            });
        });


        it('should respond with the same report saved', function (done) {
            request(app)
                .get('/api/reports/' + report._id)
                .expect(200)
                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .end(function (err, res) {
                    if (err) return done(err);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(report));
                    res.body._id.should.equal(report._id);

                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

The output I get is

```js
    {"_id":"55282d42cb39c43c0e4421e1","__v":0}
{"__v":0,"_id":"55282d42cb39c43c0e4421e1"}

1) GET:id /api/reports should respond with the same report saved:
     Uncaught AssertionError: expected '55282d42cb39c43c0e4421e1' to be 55282d42cb39c43c0e4421e1
```

If I instead use == it works fine

> (res.body._id == report._id).should.equal(true);

What I ultimately would want was for res.body (or something else for that matter) to deep equal the initial report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're Express route handler for `/api/reports/:id` uses `res.json()` to send the `Report`, the problem the mongoose document is "stringified". When a mongoose document is stringified, ObjectIds get typecasted to strings, which do not get automatically converted back to ObjectIds when parsed back go an object.

So, if you want "deep equal" the original `Report` doc with the one returned by Express, you will need to submit it to the same "conversion process". The assertion would look something like this.

```
res.body.should.eql(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(report)));
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You answer set me on the correct path, editing it for correct syntax and marking complete. res.body.should.eql(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(report)));